# WORKDIR instruction in Dockerfile has no effect when containerize a Python app

Tags: python, docker

I have the following Dockerfile to containerize a Python app:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./simple_http_server.py .
CMD [ "python", "./simple_http_server.py" ]
```

I run with the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:8000 simple_http_server
```

It runs fine. `docker ps -a` shows the container is up for `n` seconds and container id of `xyz`. Then I attach to the container to inspect inside the container using the command

```
docker exec -i  -t xyz /bin/bash
```

Once inside the container, doing a `pwd` command reveals it's inside the `/code` directory.

```
root@3df086098bf2:/code# pwd
/code
```

In fact, the `WORKDIR /app` instruction above seems to have no effect at all. I don't see `/app` anywhere.

What is the explanation of why `WORKDIR` has no effect and how it can be fixed?

Comment: It's not clear here that your `docker exec` command is actually targeting the container you started with `docker run`. Are you sure that you are?

Comment: More specifically, if `docker run` the container exits immediately, you can't `docker exec` into it.  You could `docker run --rm -it simple_http_server bash` to get a new container, based on the same image, running an interactive shell instead of your program, to figure out why it's not starting up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you built the image again after update `WORKDIR /app`, this maybe because you run the old image with `WORKDIR /code`. 
Try:

```
docker build -t simple_http_server .
```

Then:

```
docker run -dp 5000:8000 simple_http_server
```